# Unity not building to Android

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

Unity is not building to android with this error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details. 
D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Ben/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity5.5.1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error:Invalid command android
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 64
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

I have my path variables set up correctly in the Unity editor, and I believe that I have my setup all correct in the actual SDK. Here is my SDK:

[image]

I'm on Unity 5.5.1f1, and Android Studio 2.3

Comment: Follow the direction from the duplicated question. Let me know if there is a problem.

Comment: That didn't help, I am getting the same error. Here are my file paths:
`C:/AndroidSDK/sdk`
`C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_121`

@Programmer

Comment: Please put a screen shot of what your paths looks like from Unity's setting.

Comment: Work around [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-build-fails-when-the-latest-android-sdk-tools-25-dot-3-1-version-is-used)

The tools folder was broken, it is a known issue.

Comment: This problem can be caused by many things. It can be cause by using \ instead of / or by providing the wrong path. I can also be cause by updating to a version SDK Tools. Unity has been fixing them but they keep coming back once in a while. Glad you fixed it!

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should this be marked as not duplicate because it was a different issue?

Comment: I will remove the duplicate if it is a different problem. Are you sure that downloading the SDK from the linked answer did not solve the issue?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Trust me I tried several file paths to the SDK and JDK before I posted here as well.